# How to select with a binary field ? (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, binary-data

Try to select use "where" clause in a mysql statement:
e.g.
Table: X with a ID column which is BINARY data type. Then save in a variable in php

```
$aid = $row["id"];
```

How do i use this variable later when I try to select from table

```
$where = "where `ID` = '$aid'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM X ".$where;
```

Return 0 row.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why makes you say "not working"?  Do you get an error?  Does it not produce the results you expect?  Does it produce no results?

Comment: just edited. it produces no results.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question.

Just figured out:

```
$where = "where HEX(ID) = 'bin2hex($aid)'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM X ".$where;
```

Does anyone know better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

add BINARY in where clause.

```
$where = "where BINARY ID = '$aid'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM X ".$where;
```