# Error inserting binary data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error in my php script:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'M�Uɽފ�')' at line 1

and my code:

```
$Connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "12345678");
mysql_select_db("database5", $Connection);

$Hashsz = "FF381278A9AB19274D9755C9BDDE8A82";
$HashBin = pack("H*", $Hashsz);

$Query = "INSERT INTO Hashes (Hash) VALUES ('{$HashBin}')";
if(mysql_query($Query, $Connection))
{
    echo "inserted";
}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

the value type is: binary(16)

why?

Comment: You should convert the data to a text format. Check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505673/sql-query-with-binary-data-php-and-mysql.

Comment: try remove single quotes from '{$HashBin}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With old mysql extension you should use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escapes your `$HashBin`. Even better you shoud use prepared statements and parameterized queries. Read "[How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)" question.

Comment: a question, is not it supposed that $HashBin is a binary data? why should I use that function?

Comment: just print `$HashBin` and see what contains