# Convert binary(16) data in MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql

I "inherited" from a collegue a MySQL database with dozen of fields. Since I've worked very few times with databases, I'm looking for little advice here.

There's a `binary(16)` field named "IP": I suppose it is used to store user IPs. A typical stored value is, for example, `00000000000000000000ffff3d024463`.

Using PHP (or even MySQL, if this is possibile), how can I convert this data to a plain IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had to convert that number using a MySQL function (`INET6_NTOA`).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$data = hex2bin($ip);
var_dump($data);
//not sure how your data was put into the column IP
```

on your sql query you can also try

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `HEX(IP)` FROM `database`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
foreach($row['ip'] as $ip)
{
   $data = hex2bin($ip);
   echo $data."<br />";
}
```

//code not tested

[SQL Query with binary data (PHP and MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505673/sql-query-with-binary-data-php-and-mysql)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Comment: The hex2bin returns bool(false)

Comment: Does this page help at all? I honestly would change the column from binary to varchar and store ip address as string.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382738/convert-string-to-binary-then-back-again-using-php

Comment: Try `bin2hex ();`

Comment: I must not alter the database, I only can retrieve values