# How to search for encrypted value using Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, encryption, binary

I've got a Laravel codebase which records are encrypted before they are inserted in the Mysql database. The encryption is done using the [Crypto methods of the php-encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/classes/Crypto.md). If I want to find a record based on one of the encrypted values, looping over all the records works:

```
$records = TheModel::all();
foreach ($records as $record){
    if ($record->thefield == $value) {  // thefield is decrypted in the Eloquent model definition
        print $record->id;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't very scalable. The DB is still quite small, but growing quick so I need to change this code to actually do a query.

So I tried the following code:

```
$encryptedValue = \App\Crypt::encryptData($value);
$records = TheModel::where('thefield', $encryptedValue)->get();
foreach ($records as $record){
    print $record->id;
}
```

But this doesn't return anything. So I then found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505673/sql-query-with-binary-data-php-and-mysql) it is suggested to add `'0x'`, wrap it in `BIN2HEX()` or `HEX()` or add an `x` before it (like `x'abcd'`).

I tried adding `'0x'` (which doesn't work), but I'm not sure how I could incorporate the other ideas in my code.

Does anybody know how I could try out these ideas with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't solve the problem with the tools you're using.

Laravel's encryption is [randomized](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors) (this is a good thing for security, but it makes it impractical for search operations).

Check out [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet), which implements searchable encryption in a way that can be used with any database driver. There isn't currently an Eloquent ORM integration written anywhere, but it should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not actually using the Laravel encryption though, but the encryption of the php-encryption library (added to question). Any idea whether selecting using that encryption could work?

Comment: After some research and doing a simple test of encrypting the same thing multiple times, I indeed found out I cannot encrypt a value and search for that encrypted value. So I either need to loop over the values, or use Ciphersweet. I'll see which way I'll go.