# mysql.connector select query with binary values

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Using Python's mysql.connector, how can I select all records that match a tuple?

For example:

```
ids = (b'6TRsHMzWSrq0zeembo0Vbg',
       b'7Qoq53lKTk-RZOi830t3MA', 
       b'7ZGO9S3DTcGHjwrfpV0E0A')
```

And then the query would do something like:

```
query = SELECT first_name
        FROM users
        WHERE id = (ids)
```

Returning records for all users whose ID appears in the tuple

Comment: What is b? Is it a Python thing?

Comment: yeah, it's a binary value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this

```
query = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id IN " + str(list(ids))
cursor.execute(query)
```

On second thoughts, the following should also work

```
query = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id IN " + str(ids)
```

**EDIT**

OP mentions in comments that the ids are binary data returned from a previous query. In which case, taking hint from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9799853/1860929) and using [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) operator, the following query should work

```
query = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE BINARY id IN " + str(ids) ;
```

Comment: Runs into problems converting the binary values to string...should I decode them into utf-8?

Comment: @ensnare what kind of data is in `ids` tuple? It doesn't look like binary.. In any case, have a look at the [structs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to convert the strings to integer from binary.

Comment: the ids tuple contains a tuple of binary (case-sensitive) values returned from a previous query. Is there a way to do this w/o the conversion?

Comment: @ensnare Check my edits. Let me know if they work. If they don't, you will probably need to generate `hexcode` for ids and check for hexcodes.